# Send devise confirmation email manually later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-confirmable

I have added `devise :confirmable` to my model and created a before_create to skip the confirmation.

```
before_create :skip_confirmation

def skip_confirmation
  self.skip_confirmation!
end
```

I have a mailer named store_mailer.rb along with appropriate views app/views/stores/mailer/confirmation_instroctions.html.erb to send out the confirmation email.

```
class StoreMailer < Devise::Mailer
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'store/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views
end
```

confirmation_instroctions.html.erb

```
<h2>Resend confirmation instructions</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: confirmation_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, value: (resource.pending_reconfirmation? ? resource.unconfirmed_email : resource.email) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Resend confirmation instructions" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "stores/shared/links" %>
```

I'm trying to send the confirmation email with this:
`StoreMailer.confirmation_instructions(@store).deliver`

But it returns the following error: `ArgumentError in TransactionsController#create
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)`

Any ideas what might be wrong?

**Update 1**

transaction_controlller.rb

```
def create
   nonce_from_the_client = params['payment_method_nonce']
   @result = Braintree::Customer.create(
    first_name: params['first_name'],
    last_name: params['last_name'],
    :payment_method_nonce => nonce_from_the_client
   )

   if @result.success?
     puts @result.customer.id
     puts @result.customer.payment_methods[0].token
     StoreMailer.confirmation_instructions(@store).deliver
     redirect_to showcase_index_path, notice: 'Subscribed, please check your inbox for confirmation'

   else
     redirect_back( fallback_location: (request.referer || root_path),
                 notice: "Something went wrong while processing your transaction. Please try again!")
   end
 end
```

Comment: What's in `TransactionsController#create`?

Comment: its another method which i'm placing the `StoreMailer.confirmation_instructions(@store).deliver` inside

Comment: share that code also

Comment: please check update 1

Answer (score 3):

From the title seems like you are trying to manually send the email later. The proposed solution in your question is just postponing the email, not exactly manually triggering it.

If you want to forbid sending the email immediately and then to send it manually you could do it like this:

```
class RegistrationsController
...
def create
...
resource.skip_confirmation_notification!
...
end
```

Some other place where you want to trigger the email, call:

```
User.first.send_confirmation_instructions
```

`User.first` - change with your user

Answer (score 2):

```
@store.send_confirmation_instructions.deliver
```

This generates the confirmation token, as well as sends the mail.

Answer (score 0):

`confirmation_instructions` is a method defined in `Devise::Mailer` (the superclass of your `StoreMailer` class).
As you can see [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FMailer%3Aconfirmation_instructions) and [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer), it accepts 2 mandatory arguments and 1 optional.

You're invoking the method passing just one argument.
You must pass the second argument (`token`) too, like the following:

```
def create
  # ...

  # Note: I'm not sure this is the token you really need.
  # It's your responsibility check if it's correct.
  token = @result.customer.payment_methods.first.token
  StoreMailer.confirmation_instructions(@store, token).deliver

  # ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Lucas Costa, I have already tried this: `StoreMailer.confirmation_instructions(@store, token).deliver`... and returns error `undefined local variable or method token`

Comment: This is because you don't have any `token` variable defined in the scope of your method. I just updated my answer with a fix to it.

Comment: Actually I'm after a devise confirmation token, any idea on how to implement this?